# Hierarchical list view - OnChildClickListener on grandchildren

Tags: java, android, list, listview, hierarchical

I'm having trouble setting up my algorithm: I want to create a hierarchical list view (with 3 levels), and on the each grandchild click I want to call a function - f(). However I am aware that i should use a tree to do this , yet I can't figure it out how .

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thank you very much!

Something like :

```
 |->grandparent |
 ----------------
 |   ->parent   |
 ----------------
 |     -child   | <---On Click Function ();
 ----------------
```

Comment: Seeing as this question has been open for 4 hours without any comments or answers, might indicate, that you haven't done enough to explain your issue. I'd recommend you try to re-phrase the question and/or add a few drawings of what you're trying to do. Even better, if you've actually written some code, but just can't get it to work, add that code into the question as well. :-)

Comment: Still not exactly sure what you mean by grandparent, parent, child. Is what you want an `ExpandableListView` with yet another `ExpandableListView` inside or? If so, see the documentation here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html